# DataSet is not updated in visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am new to visual studio-2010. I am trying to create an application which reads data from sql database and shows on datagrid. I implemented the code which I found on internet.

here is the sql_button_Click function

```
private void sql_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         string ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='C:\\Users\\jakkulv\\Downloads\\VS projects\\employee\\employee\\SampleDatabase.mdf';Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
        string SQL = "select emp_id,first_name from employee";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        // open the connection
        conn.Open();
        //Create a SqlDataAdapter object
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, conn);
        // Call DataAdapter's Fill method to fill data from the
        // Data Adapter to the DataSet
        DataSet ds = new DataSet("employee"); //database table name is "employee"
        ds.Clear();
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        // Bind data set to a DataGrid control
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = ds.DefaultViewManager;


        if (ds.HasChanges(DataRowState.Added))
        {
            // New rows have been added to the dataset, add appropriate code.
            MessageBox.Show("data set has changes");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("data set has no changes");
            // No new rows have been added to the dataset, add appropriate code.
        }
```

but when I execute the same it is showing the message box saying - "data set has no changes".

why dataset is not updated??How to update it??

Comment: call like "acceptchanges()" that will assure that the dataset state is changed.

Comment: Are you expecting binding data to a grid to add rows to the data? Other than that, why would you expect your dataset to have changes right after filling(being loaded from the db)

Comment: @sdf Yes. I am trying to add rows to the datagrid

Answer (score 0):

Your code will always result in the message box with `data set has no changes`, since it doesn't have any changes.

The data is the same as when it comes from the database, and since you haven't modified it, removed any records or added any records, there are no changes.

Just as the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.haschanges(v=vs.110).aspx) say

> Gets a value indicating whether the DataSet has changes, including **new**, **deleted**, or **modified** rows.

Try to modify it, and then call `ds.HasChanges()` and you'll see that it will return true.

Comment: How to update the dataset with the database entries??

Comment: How do you mean 'update'? You have already read the data from the database. An update is either a **modification** of an existing row, an **addition** of a new row, or a **deletion** of a row. That would trigger an 'update' of the `DataSet`. If you want to update the underlying database, you would typically use an `SqlConnection` just as you did when you filled the `DataSet`. This though, is another question which I'm sure the answer can be found easily.

Comment: How can I show the data in Datagrid obtained from a database table?

Comment: That is also a completely different question. The original question was "Why is the dataset unchanged?", which I have answered. Use either Google and search for "dataset to datagrid" or look for similar other questions on StackOverflow. This is off topic for this specific question

Comment: Consider marking my answer as the answer, otherwise it will be displayed as an unanswered question.